# How do I pass an array with php file directories into _GET

Tags: php

I'm having trouble understanding _GET usage in this,which is mandatory for my current task. What I want to achieve is: I type in

```
...php/?page=airlines
```

I want it to display a file called airlines.php ,which I set with an associative array that has the directories of these php files,how do I go about doing this?

An example would be appreciated

Comment: If you mean you want to launch the airlines.php script then simply `header('Location: ' . $_GET['page'] . '.php');` should so that. After checking the `$_GET['page']` actually exists using something like `if ( isset($_GET['page']) ){`

Comment: So it isn't supposed to be like this? `<?php
$nav =array("home"=>"C:\xampp\htdocs\project\home.php","flight"=>"C:
mpp\htdocs\project\flight-detail.php","order"=>"C:
mpp\htdocs\project\order-flight.php,","testimonial"=>"C:
mpp\htdocs\project\add-testimonial.php");


if ( isset($_GET['home']) )
{
    header('Location: ' . $_GET['home']);
}`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data=array(
"name"=>"xyz",
"email"=>"abc@gmail.com"
);
header("location:redirectpage.php?file=airlines&filedata=$data");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to how your code works. Code only answers serve no value for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

Get page name from query URL, if page name not found set default script name to include

```
$page = ( !empty( $_GET['page'] ) ) ?  $_GET['page'] : 'default' ; 

//define path to include files from directory structure

$file_path = '/';  

if( file_exists( $file_path . $page . '.php' ) )
{
    // now include the script with the page name
    include( $file_path . $page . '.php' );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've an associate array like this.

```
<?php
    $assocArray = array(
        'file_name'=>'airlines.php'
        'file_path'=>'/assets/airlines'
    )
```

In this case we cannot pass an array to the $_GET query parameter's value. The below line should help.

```
<?php
    $queryString = http_build_query($assocArray);
    header('Location: page_to_redirect.php?'.$queryString)
    //$queryString value will be file_name=airlines.php&file_path=%2Fassets%2Fairlines
```